# Closing wpf window before opening a new one

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button that opens a WPF window which shows some calculation.

```
public void SomeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window1 win2 = new Window1();
    win2.Show();
    win2.Topmost = true;
}
```

I have a problem that if I change values in the program and press the button again, I have two open windows.
Is there a way that I can close `win1` before opening the new version of `win2`?
I tried with `win2.Close()`, but since `win2` is not known before the application creates it won't obviously work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store a reference to the window in a variable in your class:

```
private Window2 win2;
public void SomeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    win2?.Close();
    win2 = new Window2();
    win2.Show();
    win2.Topmost = true;
}
```

This will close any previous instance of `Window2` that you have created and opened in the click event handler before you open a new window.

Comment: I tried. Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0844 The local variable win2 can only be used after it has been declared. When the local variable is declaration, the MainWindow.win2 field is hidden.

Comment: Where do you put (private Window2 win2;)

Comment: Outside of the event handler, in the class, exactly as shown in the sample code. `win2` is a private variable.

Comment: @tenminmail: Of course it does. You could just copy and paste my code.

Comment: https://ibb.co/vckFx9K before you say it i tried with question marked too. It says as posted above.

Comment: @tenminmail: It should be `win2?.Close()` or `if (win2 != null) win2.Close();` And it shouldn't be `Window1 win2 = ...;`. You need to read my answer again. Hint: There is no *local* variable created.

Comment: @tenminmail: `Window1 win2 = new Window1();` should be just `win2 = new Window1();` like in my answer.

Comment: I got it. Window1 win2 = new Window1(); this was the Problem sorry.